# Android background

Tags: android

Как сделать, чтобы `background` не сжимался при появлении клавиатуры android studio?

Пробовал так:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

Но это не работает.

Comment: Попробуйте такие флаги `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"`.

Answer (score 2):

Вроде бы можно решить сразу несколькими способами

**1.** В манифесте, внутри активити, указать

`android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustPan"`

**2.** Использовать `getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable()` в вашей активити.

**3.** Использовать стили

```
<style name="Background" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/you_bg_drawable</item>
 </style>

<activity
    android:name=".ui.your_activity"
    android:theme="@style/Background"/>
```